# Index was outside the bounds of the array in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have two parameters , let's say P1 and P2. The sample expression I used for P2 is

`IIF(P1.Label="string", "null" ,Split(P1.Label," ").GetValue(0))`

When the condition is false, the split expression is working fine. But if the condition is true, I'm getting 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' error. If the condition is true, I need to pass the value "null" as varchar type.

Can someone please advice on this?

Comment: Not sure about the error. I was loading values to the first parameter using a temporary table. Later I modified the query(using union functionality instead of temporary table). Now it is working fine.

Comment: you need to reference the parameters as `Parameters!P1.Label`

Comment: Sorry. I have only included P1.label to indicate that I'm getting the label. It is not the actual expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the IIF function is that it is a *function* not a language construct. This means that it **evaluates both parameters** before passing the parameters to the function. Consequently, if you are trying to do a `Split` on a parameter that can't be split, you will still get the 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' error, even when it looks like that code shouldn't be executed due to boolean condition of the `IIF` statement.

The best way to solve this is to create a safe string splitter function in custom code where you can use real language constructs. Also, check that the string is splittable by checking it contains a space instead of checking for a special string:

```
Public Function SafeSplit(ByVal SplitThis As String) As String
    If InStr(SplitThis, " ") Then
      Return Split(SplitThis, " ")(0)
    End If
    Return "null"
End Function
```

and then use this in your report for the Value expression instead of IIF:

```
=Code.SafeSplit(Parameters!P1.Label)
```